# Typescript - how to declare argument as the type of a previously defined variable?

Tags: typescript

Consider this scenario:

```
const state = {
  user: null,
  metadata: null
}

const getters = {
  user(state) {
    return state.user
  }
}
```

In this scenario, how can I define the `state` argument of `getters.user(state)` as the `typeof` the state variable defined previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator to get the type of `state`:

```
const state = {
    user: null,
    metadata: null
}

const getters = {
    user(s: typeof state) {
        return s.user
    }
}
```

You can also use type queries to get the type of properties : `typeof state['user']`.

Note I renamed the parameter to `s`, if the name of the parameter would be the same as the `const`, `typeof` would try to return the type of the parameter as it is in scope.

Comment: ah okay, my problem was I had the argument named as "state", good to know that typeof returns the type of the parameter that's in scope. Thanks!